# Xamarin: Ошибка: Не удалось завершить операцию. Неопознанная ошибка

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

После обновления Visual Studio 2019 до версии **v16.9** перестал запускаться проект под Xamarin. В Installer'е восстановил Visual Studio, проект загрузился, но теперь вылазят неопознанные ошибки при запуске отладки.

> Ошибка: Не удалось завершить операцию. Неопознанная ошибка

Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Запустил Visual от имени администратора, всё корректно сбилдилось.